# Error on removing vmss Network Interface Configuration

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell, azure-load-balancer

Getting error on removing vmss Network InterfaceConfiguration. Here is the code:

```
$myVmss = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName 'MyApp-test-rg' -VMScaleSetName 'Myapp-vmss'
 

Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -VirtualMachineScaleSet $myVmss -Name $myVmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.IPConfigurations.Name
```

Getting error as-

```
Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration: Sequence contains no matching element
```

can someone please suggest.

EDITED:

all I am trying to do is to apply the backendpool config of basic LB to new standard LB. After following the suggestion of Joy, remove command worked but now facing issue on update-azvmss command.

```
$myVmss = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName $rgName -VMScaleSetName $vmssName
$newlb = (Get-AzLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName $rgName -Name $newLbName)
$mySubnetId = $myVmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.IpConfigurations[0].Subnet.Id
$backendPoolId = $newlb.BackendAddressPools.Id

$ipConfig = New-AzVmssIpConfig -Name MyNewConfig -SubnetId $mySubnetId -LoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolsId $backendPoolId

Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -VirtualMachineScaleSet $myVmss -Name $myVmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.Name[1]  

Add-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -Name MyNewConfig -Primary $true -VirtualMachineScaleSet $myVmss -IpConfiguration $ipConfig

$myVmss | Update-AzVmss
```

here is the error-

```
Update-AzVmss: Primary network interface configuration of VM scale set /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxxx-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/xxxxxxx cannot be changed. Original Primary network interface configuration: xxxxxx-vnet-v2-nic01, Requested: MyNewConfig.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the name of `NetworkInterfaceConfiguration`, not `IPConfiguration`, and you should note `myVmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.Name` is an array, so you need to give the specific one.

Before running `Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration`, you may need to check `$myVmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.Name` to confirm the `NetworkInterfaceConfiguration` you want to remove.

[image]

For example, you want to remove `Test`, then the command should be:

```
Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -VirtualMachineScaleSet $myVmss -Name $myVmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.Name[1]
```

---

*Just a tip:*

To make it take effect, you need to stop the VMSS, then use `Update-AzVmss` after `Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration`.

```
$myVmss = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName testvmss -VMScaleSetName myvmss 

Remove-AzVmssNetworkInterfaceConfiguration -VirtualMachineScaleSet $myVmss -Name $myVmss.VirtualMachineProfile.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaceConfigurations.Name[1]

$myvmss | Update-AzVmss
```

Comment: thanks Joy. Making that change helped the command to execute. My main motive is to migrate the backend pool of basic LB to standard LB, and hence trying to attach the backend pool config of new std LB to the vmss. on the update-azvmss i got this error-

Update-AzVmss: Primary network interface configuration of VM scale set /subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachine/.. cannot be changed. Original Primary network interface configuration: xxxxxx-vnet-v2-nic01, Requested: MyNewConfig.

Comment: Updated the question with details @joy Wang.  thanks.

Comment: @medinibster Well, if your original issue was solved, could you accept it and ask the new issue in a different post? Stackoverflow avoids asking different questions in one post, and it will be clear for others.